# Laptop adapter dies when connected to computer

Tags: ac-adapter, acer-veriton

I own am Acer Veriton l460

Yesterday I tried to start up my computer but it failed to start.

These are the assumptions I made.

- The adapter inputs 240v and outputs 19v which i both checked with a meter
- When the adapter is not connected to the PC the indicator on the adapter is stable (green, not blinking).
- When the adapter is connected to the PC it makes some cracking noise and after about 0.5 seconds the adapter dies, in the mean time the computer runs for 0.5 seconds

Is this a adapter problem or something inside the computer?

Comment: I'd say 'not enough evidence to decide' on just that info, though I would first suspect the PSU. Just because it can show a clean 19v when not under load doesn't mean it will when it is under load.

Comment: Thank you for the responds, is there anything I can do to rule out other computer components ?

Comment: I'm no electronics whizz - I'd take it to a shop & get them to test it with another PSU

Comment: Can you please be specific on what type of adapter your talking about?

Answer (score 0):

From experience... crackling inside an adapter is pretty serious... it likely means a joint has gone bad in the adapter, possibly the board in the adapter is burned as well. the fault lets just enough electricity through to run the green LED but as son as you put the laptop on to drain more power, the adapter can't cope any more.

replace the adapter, they are not repairable. In fact it is probably welded shut so you have to destructively cut it open to even see the works.